# How to stop a select menu form opening or changing?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#selectmenu').on('keyup focus mousedown', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
});
```

but when it is selected by pressing tab i can change the value by pressing up & down key.how to stop it?

Comment: why dont you disable it?

Comment: You can block the tab keypress.

Comment: dont want to disable it as its value will be submitted with form.

Comment: how can i block all the events on it?

Comment: How ever user can modify it in any case: for example with developer tools, so just add `readonly` attribute?

Comment: You can disable `select` box and set its value to input hidden fields which will get submitted with form.

Comment: Make it `readonly`. In this way you prevent changing value and still submit it to server.

Comment: yes one can change it..have added validation on server side.nothing to worry about it...i just want it for view purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Block the tab key.

```
$('/*The Previous Input */').on('keydown', function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 9) {
            e.preventDefault();
      }
});
```

I don't have your HTML, so i can't test or integrate the code.

---

You also can use **disabled="disabled"**, i think is a better solution.

Comment: worked for me. `keydown focus mousedown` events. thanks.

Comment: Remembering if you use just keydown this will block any key.

Answer (score 1):

You use `off()` or `unbind()` methods of jQuery:

```
<select id="dropDown" name="dropDown" style="margin-top: 5px; width: 150px;">
           <option value="select">Select </option>
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
           <option value="All">All </option>
</select>

<button id="stopChange" >Stop</button>
<button id="StartChange" >Start</button>
```

jQuery code:

```
$("#stopChange").click(function () {

        $("#parSelCategor").unbind("change");
    });
    $("#StartChange").click(function () {
        $("#parSelCategor").bind("change");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You may listen you a more global event like 'onchange' and change the value back to the previous one when the event trigger.

Disabling the select may work too.

Edit : 'keydown' seems like a good idea too.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the `tabindex` of the select box

```
$('#selectmenu').attr('tabindex', -1).on('keyup focus mousedown', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

or best way is just disable the control

```
$('#selectmenu').attr("disabled", true);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z8jhfw51/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that simply forces the selection to stay the same if some variable (`stopChange`) is true.

JS (jQuery):

```
var stopChange = true;
var opt = $('option:selected');

$('#selectmenu').on('change', function () {
    if (stopChange) {
        opt.attr('selected', true);
    }
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/flowstoneknight/wep3t90z/2/).